# Echarts Legend overlap Chart

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, legend, echarts

The legend of chart overlaps Chart

Heres the example of legend

```
legend={ 
        width: '95%',
        type: 'scroll',
        orient: 'vertical'
}

[![Chart][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdH0W.png
```